# FireBug didn't working

Tags: php, firefox3.6, firephp, firebug1.5

I created a index.php file located in **http://localhost/home/index.php**. The file filled with the code below.

```
<?php

# //include the file  
require_once("FirePHP.class.php");  
# //create the object  
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);  
# //send information  
$firephp->fb("Hello world!");  

?>
```

I enabled fireBug and firePHP, BTW I download firePHPCore and copy **FirePHP.class.php** to **http://localhost/home/FirePHP.class.php** directory.

To run this code I can't see the message “Hello world!” in the firebug console.

I followed the tutorial
http://yensdesign.com/2008/10/how-to-debug-php-code/

Winxp and fireFox 3.6.3; fireBug 1.5.3; firePHP 0.4.3 used.
Any suggesion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to fireBug.

**Net panel is disabled....**

Enable Net Panel. It works well. It's cool.

Thank you.